# How to find if cell contains specific characters in specific positions?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a macro that will search a given cell for a certain character combination in a specific order, and then paste this to another page.  I need it to search a cell that contains a 9 letter/number combination for '9P', but only if it's the third and fourth number/letter in.

So if given these list of entries:

```
NA9PK99LJ
NA9PK99LK
XX9P109LH
XX9P109XF
XX849P01D
NA8419PZ3
XX9P109VK
```

I'd only want it to copy the first four and the last entry, and then past these vertically starting in A2 on another page.

I'm somewhat of a novice to excel vba, but I'm told this should be doable.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Have a look at `Mid(string, 3, 2) = "9P"`

Comment: use the mid function for identifying your valid copies, have that in a loop through all the cells in your starting list.  Have a counter to keep track of howmany pastes you do so you can easily populate the correct row.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, may have gone over board

```
Sub Solution()

Dim search As String, start As Integer, lastaddress As String, toworksheet As String

lastaddress = "A2" 'cell location on the result sheet
search = InputBox("Enter Search Critera") 'enter search critera
start = InputBox("Start from") 'integer of where to search in the string, not zero index
toworksheet = InputBox("Put results into which spreadsheet") 'worksheet name to put results

'select the cell you want to start your search from and it will continue till it reaches a    blank cell
Do While ActiveCell.Text <> ""

'Performs the test
If Mid(ActiveCell.Text, start, Len(search)) = search Then

'adds the entry to the results sheet
Worksheets(toworksheet).Cells.Range(lastaddress).Value = ActiveCell.Text
'updates the address to the next line in your results sheet
lastaddress = Worksheets(toworksheet).Cells.Range(lastaddress).Offset(1, 0).Address
End If

'goes to next item in list
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Rob this looks like it's actually spot on what I was looking for, though maybe a little more advanced than I imagined.  I can't seem to get this to work though, and I think I'm running into the issue when it's asking me where to start from.  I'm not sure what I'm doing in correctly that I can't get it to populate.  Also, I notice in the code that it pastes the first 4 and the last digits to the other sheet, is it possible to paste the entire set of 9 numbers if this criteria is met, rather than as it is now?  Ideally I'm trying to split this large list into separate sheets.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries, select the first cell in your list of data before you start the method. The code doesn't create a new worksheet so create the sheet yourself with the relevant name and use the name when it asks where to put your results. Then change Mid(ActiveCell.Text, 1, 4) +     Right(ActiveCell.Text, 1) ------------ Activecell.Text  this will take the entire text in your item in your list and put it to the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of is to use Find() with wildcards. What you can do is use the macro recorder while doing the following:

- Start the macro recorder
- Select the range to search
- Do Ctrl + F and enter `??9P?????` into the search terms
- Select all the results in the box
- Close the box, copy the cells and paste them where you want
- Stop the macro recorder

This will give you the main base of your code which you can then fine tune so that it does what you need. This is also a good exercice for you to learn how VBA works.

Comment: I've sparingly used the record macros function before, but being as this list changes and the numbers in this list will never be the same each time this is ran, I don't think that this is a viable solution.  Thank you for taking the time to respond though, I appreciate it!

Comment: I don't see how this does not work. You can edit the range to make sure it is wide enough to fit your needs and the term to input in the find box uses wildcards which makes it even more flexible. Do you mean that it can be something else than 9P ? Then put it in a cell and just reference that in the term instead of the hard-coded `9P`.